# Show and hide spinner when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html

How can I show and hide a spinner (using the spin.js) when the page loads, and when the user does an AJAX request? I was thinking of the onload message for starting the spinner, but that event means that the content has been loaded so probably a bad place to place it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read a lot more about AJAX. Mentioning the onLoad event while talking about AJAX requests is a bit weird, for me.

Just a hint: Start showing the spinner on starting the AJAX request, and stop it after your request returned what you wanted to / is complete.

- [Ajax fast and easy](http://blog.webandnow.com/blog/2008/02/17/ajax-fast-and-easy/)
- [w3schools ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)
- [Ajax example](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php)
- [a list of tutorials](http://www.javascriptsource.com/ajaxTutorials)
- Maybe also interesting: [jQuery (for absolute beginners)](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-day-2/)

Answer (score 0):

In AJAX request better to start spinner before AJAX call and hide at success response.

When the page loads you can add `<script>` tag where you load spinner after `<body>` tag, and when `onload` event is fired hide that spinner.

Comment: I really see no point why you would work with the "onLoad" event of your body tag. Especially if we talk about AJAX! It means, your body document can be finished loading data, but the AJAX request not! This sir is no good solution! He just should learn / read more about ajax to get it working! If he uses a framework (jQuery, Prototype w/e) or not. I'd say first, NOT, to understand AJAX, and then decide for a framework!

Comment: @creativeby Maybe you should read the question again, and then you will see that I don't ask only about AJAX.